# Only display certain checkout fields if there's a product in the cart from a certain channel

Tags: cartthrob, conditionals, ecommerce

I've got different types of products (in different channels) in a CartThrob store. Is it possible to add a conditional within the [Checkout Form tag](http://cartthrob.com/docs/tags_detail/checkout_form/) to enable certain checkout fields to only appear if there's a product from a certain channel in the cart? If so, how would I go about doing this?

I've been looking at the [Checkout Form tag](http://cartthrob.com/docs/tags_detail/checkout_form/) and the [Cart Items Info tag](http://cartthrob.com/docs/tags_detail/cart_items_info/index.html), but there doesn't appear to be anything here to test for what I'm looking for (please correct me if I'm wrong!). I also looked at the [Is In Cart tag](http://cartthrob.com/docs/tags_detail/is_in_cart/index.html), but this only seems to work for adding one entry ID at a time, not looping through lots of entry_id's in a channel (which rules out adding all the entries in this particular channel, though that might have been impractical anyway).

There is a [Cart Entry ID's tag](http://cartthrob.com/docs/tags_detail/cart_entry_ids/index.html), but I can't figure out how to use this in a conditional that would output a single true/false result (for use in a conditional) if one of the pipe-delimited entry ID's belonged to a certain channel. Thanks for any advice on this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can probably get this done with stash. This is off the top of my head so please refer to the Stash documentation.

```
{exp:stash:set name="is_engravable" parse_tags="yes" parse_conditionals="yes" default="0"}{exp:cartthrob:cart_items_info}{if channel_name == "engravable_products"}1{/if}{/exp:cartthrob:cart_items_info}{/exp:stash:set}

{exp:stash:parse process="end"}
  {exp:cartthrob:checkout_form}
  {if {exp:stash:not_empty name="is_engravable"}}
  <label>Engraving</label>
  <input type="text" name="order_engraving">
  {/if}
  {/exp:cartthrob:checkout_form}
{/exp:stash:parse}
```

Comment: Thanks for this Rob. I don't use Stash, but I'll have a play around with CE Variables to see if that can do the same sort of thing, or if not, will come back to Stash.